# ¿Cómo puedo abrir un modal al seleccionar el radio button con id="sí"? Sin agregar la etiqueta form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: Este es el código que estuve intentando]

> Este es el código que estuve intentando

Comment: Estaría bien que incluyas el código en vez de una captura.

Comment: Aquí se indica [por qué no hay que compartir el código como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). ¡No ignores los comentarios! Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con algo como esto deberías conseguirlo. Por supuesto hay mejores formas de hacerlo separando el código js en otro archivo, pero básicamente esto funciona.

```
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="si" onclick="ejecuta()">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ejecuta(){
                $("#Modal").modal("show");
            }
        </script>
```

Por otro lado, si sólo es al pulsar sobre el botón radio y te da igual el valor porque sólo es sobre ese botón, puedes poner el código que abre el modal en cualquier parte:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#Modal">
```

[Modal en Radio Button](https://codepen.io/JavierSantos/pen/abypdJm) CodePen.